# reading value from textbox in mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on old mvc application, and I'm trying to read value from textbox (textmode = "Date"), but in Text attribute I got empty string, how can I fix this? The code is below

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DateFrom" autocomplete="off" runat="server" textmode="Date" Width="150px" Height="20px" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox><br />

DateTime dateFrom = DateTime.Parse(DateFrom.Text); //DateFrom.Text = """
```

Comment: Do you fill the textbox on creation?

Comment: of course, it is always filled (DateFrom.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");)

Comment: Do you maybe have some js scripts that erase the textbox value? For example some libraries, that restyle the textbox in a particular way?

Comment: everything is okay with that, when I change TextMode from Date to DateTime it works, but this type of data makes a problem

Comment: have you tried by Convert.ToDateTime(dateValueString) ?

Comment: it's empty .text value, program crashes when I try to convert, but in reality that .text value mustn't be empty, I choose some date, and when I try to debug it, programs says DateFrom.Text = ""